# How to get the key of the maxium value in a dictionary and also return the highest number key if there is a duplicate

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates, max

(sorry for vague title)

```
dic = {1:20, 2:20, 3:20, 4:10}
```

I want it to return 3, because that's the highest key number between the three duplicate values in the dictionary.

What I currently have is:

```
return max(dic, key = dic.get)
```

But this won't get my desired result and will return 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maximize over (value, key) pairs:

```
k, _ = max(dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[::-1])
```

dict items are tuples, and tuples are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

Comment: What does the k, _ and the lambda do? I'm sorry I'm new to python

Comment: The lambda reverses each item, with the effect that "highest value" takes precedence over "highest key" in each pair.  The max returns a pair, but you only care about the first item in the pair here, so an assignment to `_` indicates "throwing away" the other item.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to [@wim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67512239/1249581):

```py
k, _ = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[::-1])[-1]
```

Comment: Just to be clear `sorted()` needs to do quite a bit more work than `max()` right? Is there any reason to use this instead of `max()`?

Comment: Slightly more, but I guess it depends on the implementation. `max` also needs to run through all elements in the collection and do comparison by `key`. @wim's answer is a no-brainer here, by all means.

Comment: Seems like it would be `O(n)` vs `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: Yes, in the best case. There is no particular reason to use this solution, it was given purely for illustration.

Comment: The difference between `sort` and `max` is really small for most applications. If the difference really matters, perhaps you should consider other alternatives faster than Python.